# Prevent Java Applet from gaining Focus

Tags: focus, keyboard-shortcuts, applet

An applet gains focus when loaded, preventing browser keystrokes from working. You can work around this by adding a parameter to the applet tag:

name="initial_focus" value="false"

So far so good. But when the user clicks on the applet even if the applet does not have any user interface controls, then the problem remains.

I guess another way to phrase the question is: How can I get the applet to forward all keystrokes back to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a button click handler to the parts of your application that doesn't have a UI (for example your root pane), and execute a piece of javascript code that will be run by the browser, delegating the focus to some HTML DOM element instead.